# Custom tag buttons

Tags: feature-request

Interesting tags are great. However I would like to be able to specify languages for language agnostic tags.

I got the following interesting tags:

- c#
- multithreading
- asp.net-mvc
- .net
- spark-view-engine
- sockets
- nosql
- design-patterns
- architecture

The problem is that I am not interested in all `architecture`/`multithreading`/`other language agnostic tag` questions, just those that are in my favorite languages.

It would be nice if I could define my own buttons (`[architecture] AND ([.net] OR [c#] OR [vb.net]`) instead of clicking on the interesting tag buttons.

A custom search wont do since it's sorted by relevance and not by timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting idea.

You can already do a similar thing if you save a URL of such search and add it as a bookmark. If your browser has bookmark toolbars you can even make it a button, then.

Comment: +1 true. It would be nicer to have the links/buttons directly in SO though.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is not you want, but

> [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) AND ([.net](/questions/tagged/.net) OR [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) OR [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net))

can be specify as

> [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) AND [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) OR [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) AND [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) OR [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) AND [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)

So

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture%2bc%23%2bor%2barchitecture%2b.net%2bor%2barchitecture%2bvb.net?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: +1. that works. Now only if I could define own links/buttons in right column.